# How to Wrap unspaces word for Opera Browser

Tags: css, opera

I am currently testing this function in all browser using php.

```
<style>
#preview_desc{
    text-wrap: suppress;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE>=5.5 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* For Fx<=2 */   
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* Fx>3, Opera>8, Safari>3 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-line;
    width:158px; 
    padding-left:5px; 
    padding-right:5px; 
    line-height:12px; 
    font-family:'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:11px; 
    text-align:justify;
    background:#f30000;
}
</style>

<div id="preview_desc" 
class="adlookmsg_box">
Refeforotherapplicationandcontainasdhlsakfhnaiufalsdufgnaloskdufglkjblfasug
</div>
```

However only in Opera browser that not process the wrapping or the unspace word.
Please if any can help with this. Tks

--Edited--
note: sorry bout this appereance.

Comment: Hai? Where's the PHP part, and what does it have to do with CSS?

Comment: What version of opera? Should work: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html

Comment: @deceze: sorry i mean css.. tks for the correction

Comment: @kobi: I am now using Opera ver 10.10 (latest)

Comment: @S. Mark, too bad SO doesn't say when someone else is editing a question. Could have saved one of us some time :)

Comment: Yeah, Status msg would be very helpful, when I click submit button, its was freeze no response actually, I did F5 and I have noticed that you did already in 15 seconds ago, and I wrongly overwritten your update.

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Opera 10.10 also, I can regenerate your problem, but unfortunately I don't have good/proper answer, but a hack here. **Do it If there is no other way**. Put following codes to end of the document.

```
<script>
     x=document.getElementById("preview_desc");
     x.innerHTML=x.innerHTML.replace(/(.)/g,"$1\u200b");
</script>
```

It will put \u200b (Zero Width Space) character after every characters, so Opera would able to handle that..

**UPDATE**: Only add \u200b to long words, currently set as 10+, you may need to adjust it.

```
<script>
    x=document.getElementById("preview_desc");
    x.innerHTML=x.innerHTML.replace(/[\w]{10,}/g,function(x){return x.replace(/(.)/g,"$1\u200b");});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi S.Mark
Thanks for your answer. It is works fine. 
However, new problem occur, any style related to font e.g. <strong> or <u> is showing the tag name not showing the result.
Why is that?

Comment: Oops! got it, So you have html tags inside "preview_desc", hold on please, I will update it to works only for long words.

Comment: Hi S.Mark
It work perfectly. Thank you so much. 
Hope you wouldn't mind if I'll ask you some other time.

Comment: Hi Mark.. 
The solution that you give me, there is some little problem.
Last time I tried the whole chars inside 1 tag, however, if I put the html tags at diff part of chars, the function isn't work.
FYI, mine using tinyMCE for textarea.
Tks.