# content not taking height of it's parent element

Tags: html, whitespace

i have a table in which there are several td's that contain link now problem is that my links are very long so i want those to take full width of td and then go to second line but it's not working

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/6pyxB/1/

i tried using `white-space:no-wrap;` and it's fine in cases where link size is just equal to or less than the td height. but if link size is greater than td size it will extend the td width also that i don't want.

**Demo After white-space:no-wrap**

http://jsfiddle.net/6pyxB/2/

in this case i want that remaining link address go to second line instead increasing the size of div.

Please help me out

Comment: is there supposed to be some CSS in this fiddle?

Comment: @crowjonah updated my question have a look now

Comment: In your first fiddle, the text is wrapping.  What's the problem?  Are you trying to have the text broken in the middle of a word?

Comment: @jdigital that's the problem that it is wrapping. i want it to wrap after occupying full width of td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding [word-break](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) to your stylesheet:

```
td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: is it cross browser compatible? i don't think so

Comment: The reference link (in the answer above) says this solution is compatible with all major browsers except Opera.

Comment: any solution or fix for opera?

Comment: You could try the approach described in this article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899453/how-to-wrap-unspaces-word-for-opera-browser) but it's an ugly hack.