# Why table width is ignored?

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I coded style in the following:

```
table.gridtable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 400px;
}
```

and I see no overridings in Firebug. Nevertheless table width is computed as 812 px;

Why?

Actual page is here (in Russian): http://garmonia-znakomstva.ru/service.html

**UPDATE**

Can I add invisible word breaks, which would cause word breaking and hyphen if insufficient space and continuous word if enough space?

Comment: Interesting that the CSS `width` rule isn't present in the style of the document to which the URL is linking...

Comment: Yes it is: `style.css:332`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The width setting is not ignored; it is just overridden, by the minimum requirements of cell contents. In each column, the longest word determines the smallest possible width. This is in accordance with CSS specifications: for a table, the `width` property is by default just a suggested minimum width.

“Smallest possible” is relative, though. You can enable word division in different ways. But to see where this would take you to, you can test by changing the `<html>` tag to `<html lang=ru>` and by adding the rule `* { -moz-hyphens: auto }` to your CSS and testing the page on Firefox. You will see the table formatted so that words are hyphenated and the width is as close to the declared width as you can get that way. It looks rather awful. The declared width is simply too small for the content.

Alternatively, try setting `table { table-layout: fixed }` in CSS. This will enforce the width, no matter what. And this will make cell content overflow out of the cells. I don’t think you’ll like this either.

I would thus suggest that you don’t try to enforce such a narrow width but rather remove the width setting entirely and enable hyphenation. The result looks relatively good. For hyphenation, I would suggest using [Hyphenator.js](https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator), a JavaScript-based approach that works across browsers; CSS-based approach still has rather limited browser support.

Comment: Wrong link. This is the right one: http://mnater.github.io/Hyphenator/ (even if I can find a "demo" but only a long text to be read... )

Comment: I updated the link to Hyphenator and removed the link to a demo.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is caused by the fact that the individual words in each cell of the table are too long, and you haven't specified how this should be dealt with.

Try adding:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

To your `table.gridtable td` rule.

Comment: Using `word-break: break-all` is wrong for Russian, as for most languages. It means br eaking wor ds arbit rarily without eve n indicat ing the b reaks.

Comment: I believe this answer is correct and regarding the `break-all` value, well, if you know css, you know there is also `break-word` option, if your table contains meaningful words that need to be broken up on actual word boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

It's because there are words in the table, which cannot be wrapped by default, thus the table cannot shrink. The effect will occur:

```
| verylongwordandsoon | anotherlongwordinrussian | justanotherword
```

If you try to set the `font-size` to `1px`, you will see that the width is exactly 400 pixels.

However, in CSS3, the CSS property `word-break` can handle it.

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: That's not true. Using CSS3 etc., words *can* be wrapped (see my answer).

Comment: @BenM: It is. Usually it *cannot*, but indeed in CSS3, it can be defined. (I was just still writing my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Applying this explicitly gave me the right result, width is respected, long text using new lines and height (instead width) expanding accordingly.

```
td { white-space:normal}
```

Comment: All other suggestions work to some extent, but either not in complex contexts (tabel in div in div etc.), or indeed, breaking words arbitrarily. Adding * {white-space: normal} to the stylesheet proved to be the most comprehensive and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a table too small for its contents.  You might try reducing the font size or trying a different layout (like using fewer columns).

Regarding your updated question: yes, you can add invisible word breaks (here's one example: [How to Wrap unspaces word for Opera Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899453/how-to-wrap-unspaces-word-for-opera-browser)) but this is really a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Your css file could already be defining `white-space: nowrap;` which would prevent word wrapping.